# Как передать данные таблицы html в функцию

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Всем доброго времени суток. Проблема такая,  у меня есть таблица `html`, нужно эту таблицу экспортировать в `excel`. Я использую библиотеку `exceljs`, основной проблемный момент - это передать значения таблицы в эту библиотеку для вывода в файл `XLSX`

Вот основные этапы передачи

```
const wsTitle = 'value';
var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(wsTitle);
worksheet.getCell('A1').value = wsTitle;
```

Для наглядности вот код который создает напрямую заголовок и строку, а мне нужно как то передавать в `WORKSHEET.COLUMNS` содержимое таблицы, т.к. будет несколько таблиц на нескольких страницах

```
worksheet.columns = [

   { header: 'Head', key: 'id', width: 15 },
   { header: 'Title', key: 'title', width: 25, style: {alignment: {wrapText: true}}},
   { header: 'test', key: 'test', width: 25, style: {alignment: {wrapText: true}}}

];

worksheet.addRow({id: 1, title: 'John Doe', test:'YOMF'});
```

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, уже пробовал парсить в `json` и передавать в эту функцию, но ничего хорошего не произошло.

Comment: обычная таблица thead tbody tfoot, я перебрал значения

`var table_thead = $('#table thead tr').each(function (index, element) {
     $(this).each(function(index_x, element_x) {
      console.log(element_x);
     })
     });`


в консоли выводит эти значения (пока только thead) но все-таки не пойму как засунуть их в функцию чтобы они были внесены в excel файл, скачивание использую обычный blob

Comment: Вам нужен парсер из HTML в EXCEL. Таблицу можно экспортировать в поддерживаемый формат Excel называемый csv (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Все просто на самом деле и я не знаю зачем вам библиотека для подобной задачи.

Comment: Кстати я бы еще посоветовал использовать JQ и просто пройтись в таблице по рядам. `$.each` для `tr` внутри которого второй `$.each` для `td`.

Comment: @Telion дело в том, что мало библиотек смогут экспортировать картинку в base64 и впихнуть ее в excel)))  поэтому сказали использовать exceljs, в данной ситуации где мы создаем worksheet.columns я непойму как передать значения из моей таблицы а именно tr th

Comment: Окей(я не говорю что так надо делать, я делюсь знаниями). Но если хотите конвертировать картинку в base64 вот я тут нашел пару ответов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript. На счет библиотеки врядли смогу помочь, впервые вижу.

Comment: @Telion я очень вам благодарен) пройтись по рядам я пытаюсь так же через each) 

`var table_thead = $('#table thead tr').each(function (index, element) { 
  $(this).each(function(index_x, element_x) { console.log(element_x); }) });`


но полученные значения не особо получается вывести в excel(((

Comment: не особо, тоесть есть хоть какой-то результат? как вы заносите в эксель

Comment: @qwabra я использую библиотеку exceljs 
`const wsTitle = 'value'; // Store our title in a variable
var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(wsTitle);
worksheet.getCell('A1:').value = wsTitle;`
 вот у меня создается рабочий лист, далее я пытаюсь перебрать tr и th циклом JQ и мне нужно занести это все в таблицу excel, ну как указано в документации то вот так, только вместо значений "рукописных" нужно передавать значения из моей таблицы( вот сижу голову ломаю

Comment: @qwabra
worksheet.columns = [

     { header: 'test1', key: 'id', width: 15},
     { header: 'test2', key: 'title', width: 25},
     { header: 'test3', key: 'test', width: 25}
    
     ];

     worksheet.addRow({id: '1', title: 'val', test:'YOMF'});

Comment: @Telion есть идеи на этот счет?

Comment: у вас установлен Exel?(у меня нет) нашел такой пример https://jsfiddle.net/r8bx18kx/ щелкните по кнопке экспорт и проверьте в Exel загружаются ли картинки

Comment: проверьте, будет ли рабртать с base64

Comment: @qwabra работает, но не сохраняет в формате xlsx, даже когда поменял формат

Comment: работает с `base64` ?? если да, так всё просто! ©не сохраняет в формате xlsx - а оно вам надо ?!

Comment: @qwabra ага, оч важно) с base64 работает.
объясню картину как должно быть: есть параметры их куча, и при клике на него вылезает график и таблица, там снизу кнопка "скачать" и вах бабах создается файлик excel где таблица и снизу график

Comment: Как я говорил я мало чем смогу помочь, как и в принципе большинство. Задавать вопросы про непопулярные библиотеки тухлая тема :( Я порылся в инете я полагаю `exceljs` не имеет встроенных способов создать граф. Зато я нашел другую с названием `SheetJS` (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) которая пишет в формат `.xlsx`, имеет неплохую документацию и вопрос на гите про чарты был отвечен (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/925).

Comment: да, он неплох, но он мне в base 64 формате не экспортирует график - проверенно(  всеравно большое спасибо за ответы)

Comment: @ПашаХарченко, не, смотрите, если у вас с приведённой вами библиотекой получается работать как вам нужно, в том числе с ! картинками (workbook.addImage - странная конструкция) - то помочь с разбором таблицы я могу

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте [вот](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Table-To-Excel-Bold-Headers.html) замечательная и простая библиотека для экспорта в `Excel` и вот пример js кода что вам понадобиться для её использования.
**Обязательно подключите после Jquery**

```
$('table').tableExport({  //ваша таблица 
filename: 'example.xls'// имя файла 
escape: 'true', // убрать escape символы
htmlContent: 'true' //убрать вёрстку
});
```

Comment: XLS (((  а нужно XLSX(((

Answer (score 0):

с задачей справился, все очень помогли, воспользовался библиотекой exceljs, когда разобрался оказалась очень простой

```
var arr_head = [];
var get_head = $('#table thead tr').each(function (index, element) {    
var elements = $(element).find("th");
 $(elements).each(function(index_head, element_head) {
 arr_head.push({ header: $(element_head).text(), width: 15});
    });

});

 worksheet.columns = arr_head;
```

это сама процедура поиска по элементам таблицы и занеения в массив, в итоге мы просто обращаемся к нашей библиотеке к свойствам колонок и ложим туда наши значения , это повторяется с tbody, theader,tfoot,если есть вопросы задавайте))